# How develop Wrapper to consume the Amadeus Web service

Tags: amadeus

I want to develop Wrapper to consume the Amadeus Web service .. How to start the Project. Need to create all the classes which is Amadeus reference and how to convert the response in simple response. Any one have idea then please let me know
Please give me high level idea.

Finally i have to parse the Amadeus Response to other Service response.

Comment: Amadeus has documentation, support, examples and training. Contact them!

Answer (score 0):

1. You need access to Amadeus Web Services Documentation.
2. You need a Amadeus web service account (user, password, wsap, etc).

Then you have 2 options:

Option 1: Download WSDL and depending on your language, typically the IDE will generate all the clases for you, you will have to use the proxy client class in order to execute Amadeus services.

Option 2: Create Amadeus XML's yourself and send them using a HttpWebRequest.